# How do graph dependencies work with `tf.cond`?

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming that there are separate dependencies for both the True and False case:

Does tensorflow assume both dependencies are required and thus process the full subgraph for both the True and the False case? Or does it:

1. Process the dependencies for the boolean expression, then
2. Process the dependencies for either the True xor the False side of the `tf.cond(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) function is designed to execute **only one** of the true or false branches, **after** evaluating the boolean expression. For example, if you wrote something like the following:

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
condition = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=[])

op_to_run = tf.cond(condition, lambda: v.assign_add(1), lambda: v.assign_sub(1))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "0"

for _ in range(3):
  sess.run(op_to_run, feed_dict={condition: True})

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "3"

for _ in range(5):
  sess.run(op_to_run, feed_dict={condition: False})

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "-2"
```

Note however, that you must make sure that any side-effecting op are defined **inside** the `lambda` (or equivalently the function) that you pass to `tf.cond()`. If the side-effecting ops are defined **outside** the `tf.cond()` they will execute unconditionally:

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
condition = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=[])

# N.B. DO NOT DO THIS! Both side-effecting ops are defined outside the `tf.cond()`
# so they will both execute, regardless of the condition.
inc_op = v.assign_add(1)
dec_op = v.assign_sub(1)

op_to_run = tf.cond(condition, lambda: inc_op, lambda: dec_op)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "0"

# Both the `assign_add()` and `assign_sub()` will run, cancelling each other out.
for _ in range(3):
  sess.run(op_to_run, feed_dict={condition: True})

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "0"

# Both the `assign_add()` and `assign_sub()` will run, cancelling each other out.
for _ in range(5):
  sess.run(op_to_run, feed_dict={condition: False})

print(sess.run(v))  # ==> "0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and caution. Inside the lambda was a command to either `dequeue` samples from one queue or `dequeue` samples from another queue and I'm just passing in a boolean placeholder to tell it which, and certainly didn't want both to occur.

Comment: @DavidParks if you want to get in depth, you can look how "Switch/Merge"  work. Those are added by `tf.cond`, but also you can make execution of parts of your graph conditional by inserting those statements, here's an example -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/d67410e240369736fc4ba0267250ef27  Description of merge logic is here -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/01daba61e3a5099c6ad6439fa47e30c71560f06b/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc#L2391